Defining matrix function through its diagonalization
Suppose $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is a smooth function. Let $Dg(n)$ be the set of diagonal $n \times n$ matrices, and define $\overline{f}:Dg(n) \to Dg(n)$ in the following way: first, for a diagonal matrix $D=diag(\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_n)$,
$$\overline{f}(D)=diag(f(\lambda_1),\dots,f(\lambda_n)).$$
For a general diagonalizable matrix $A=PDP^{-1}$, define
$$\overline{f}(A)=P \overline{f}(D) P^{-1}.$$
What are the properties of $\overline{f}$? Is it still smooth?
Motivation: the idea is to find a different way to show that the exponential matrix and logarithm are smooth functions, which would be a particular case of above when $f=\exp,\log$ respectively.

First, some nitpicking: you say that $\overline{f}$ is defined on diagonal matrices, but clearly you actually want to define it on diagonalizable matrices. Second, $\exp$ and $\log$ are functions on all matrices, not necessarily diagonalizable, and you might want to say something about that case as well.
Everything is very nice if $f$ is not only smooth but analytic (which is the case for $\exp$ and $\log$), in which case you can appeal to the holomorphic functional calculus. Basically what this means is that if $f$ is defined by a convergent power series $f(z) = \sum c_n (z - a)^n$ then it can be extended to a function on matrices via
$$f(A) = \sum c_n (A - aI)^n.$$
This automatically satisfies $f(PDP^{-1}) = P f(D) P^{-1}$ provided that we take care of convergence. If $f$ has radius of convergence $r$ then $f(A)$ converges provided that the eigenvalues of $A - aI$ are all less than $r$ in absolute value, and restricted to such matrices, $f$ is still an analytic function, and in particular is smooth. For $\exp$ you can use the usual Taylor series with $a = 0$, and for $\log$ you can use the usual Taylor series with $a = 1$. That is, we define
$$\exp A = \sum_{n \ge 0} \frac{A^n}{n!}$$
$$\log A = \sum_{n \ge 1} \frac{(-1)^{n-1} (A - 1)^n}{n}.$$
